# Is it possible to change the configuration of CSS3 animation by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I was often told that the clients don't want to use CSS3 animation instead of that of JQuery. And they also thought JQuery was too "heavy".

So I'm going to implement the animation by pure CSS and pure Javascript. Javascript is used to trigger and set the configuration of animation base on different situation. One trouble I'm facing is how to set the configuration of animation?

Suppose I have a simple CSS transition:

```
.box {
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

So how to change the "2s" to "3s"? Should I set all of the animation styles to the "style" attribute of the element?

Comment: Well provide fiddle of what you want

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame